# Install OCI driver on PyQt4

Tags: driver, pyqt4, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to install the OCI driver on PyQt4 on windows and I can't find any helpful solution... All I found was how to install the OCI driver on Qt ([here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qoci)), but how can I make it work on pyqt ?
I found the sqldriver folder but there is no oci folder nor oci.pro file.

Does anyone have any advice to make it work please ?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: I managed to build the OCI driver properly (it works on Qt4 in C++) but i still did'nt find a way to link it with PyQT... I added the library path "C:/Qt/4.8.5/plugins", where the qsqloci.dll is, to my PyQt4 application, but I have this log :
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/Qt/4.8.5/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqloci4.dll"
The file 'C:/Qt/4.8.5/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqloci4.dll' is not a valid Qt plugin.
not a plugin"